# Looking for code for matching a string and fetching data in another sheet of same excel using VB

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am a beginner in EXCEL and VB script. I have 2 sheets in an excel and want to look for a string in column B of sheet 1, and if it matches, the value from same row but column A should be fetched and displayed in cell D3 of sheet 2 as "The name is _____", where in the blank the fetched value should be displayed. Please help with the code. Thanks.

Tried with below code. Stuck at val2 line, as it is throwing error. Iknow code will have many mistakes, please let me know the mistakes as I just started. Thanks for your help:

```
Sub to_approve()

Dim val1 As String    
Dim val2 As String    
Dim val3 As String    
Dim k As Integer

For k = 2 To 955    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate    
    val1 = "It is good"    
    val2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Range("B:B").Find(val1, , xlValues, xlWhole)    

    If val1 = val2 Then
        val3 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & k).Value                  
    End If    
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Added. Please review.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you can achieve the same thing with a normal formula on cell `D3`. I put your value to find on `E1`, but you can put it directly in the formula with `"It is good"` if you want.

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$955,MATCH($E$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$955,0),2)`

**How it works:**`=INDEX`

`INDEX` returns a value based on the address in a table of contents

`=INDEX(The Area of the Table , ROW , Column)`

**How it works:**`=MATCH`

`MATCH` finds a value in a range:

`=MATCH(Value to find, Column/Row where to find it, less_than/equal/greater_than)`